# Django disable database ssl using python-alpine docker image

Tags: django, mysql-python, alpine-linux

I'm trying to create a Django app using docker. Because of some problem, I want to connect with database without using ssl/tls.
When I use local environment, or docker image ubuntu, it work fine when I adding these code under `DATABASES` in `settings.py`

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'ssl_mode': 'DISABLED',
},
```

But when I swap using python-alpine (because image ubuntu is too big), it return an error

```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: MySQL client library does not support ssl_mode specification
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine

WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev mariadb-dev

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

As I know, the problem is on the connector. When I use ubuntu image, the connector is `libmysqlclient-dev`, but in alpine it is `mariadb-dev`, which not allow `ssl_mode` option.

So the question is:

1. How to disable ssl using `mariadb-dev`
2. Is there any other image that is more lightweight than ubuntu but allow me to use `libmysqlclient-dev`
3. Is there any other way to connect to my database with ssl disabled

Thank you in advance!